# Install problem in Linux

Tags: boot

New to Linux and trying to upgrade to ubuntu, the only download I see is ******.iso? I loaded this on an USB stick and rebooted puter but nothing, computer is set to boot from USB. HELP........

Comment: Are you currently running ubuntu and trying to upgrade to a newer version, or are you currently running Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Simply placing the *.iso on the usb will not work. You need to use a utility such as `unetbootin`.

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

This will take you through the process of using that *.iso to create a bootable USB stick.

Some other alternatives:

[How to create a bootable USB stick
on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

[How to create a bootable USB stick
on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)